# how to show image from /storage/app/public in lumen?

Tags: php, lumen

I got response from API with JSON format have contents filename, created time, user_id, and URL. So I want to show the image from response in frontend by put the URL in `<img src={props.generated} alt="image"/>`. Nothing was wrong in my frontend code, but the image was not shown.

here my image URL from response

`http://localhost:8000/storage/public/user_3/1594265090.jpeg`

and when I access URL, here the response in browser

`The requested resource /storage/public/user_3/1594265090.jpeg was not found on this server.`

Here my code

```
        $response = $this->client->request('POST', 'API', $data);

        $image = $response->getBody()->getContents();
        $filePath = 'public/' . $this->getUserDir();
        $fileName = time().'.jpeg';         

        if ($result = Storage::put($filePath . '/' . $fileName, $image)) {
                $generated =  $model::create([
                    'name' => $fileName,
                    'file_path' => $filePath,
                    'type' => 'motif',
                    'customer_id' => Auth::id()
                ]);

                return response($generated);
```

Image put in `/storage/app/public`, I'm sure it happens because the location of directory.
I'm already trying to execute command `mklink /D "./storage/app/public" "./public/storage"` and I got response `Cannot create a file when that file already exists.`

Comment: Read https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/filesystem#the-public-disk. The "laravel" way of linking the public folder's storage folder is "php artisan storage:link"

Comment: @KurtFriars I'm using lumen btw, it is written in the title of the question

Comment: You can still use artisan with lumen, however there is a restricted set of command. I don't use lumen, so perhaps storage:link is not available?

Comment: @KurtFriars I got error response `There are no commands defined in the "storage" namespace.` using `storage:link`

Comment: Ah, ok. Hopefully someone can help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

thankyou for your suggestion in this question. It was already solved.

I'm using `ln -rs ./storage/app/public ./public/storage`. But this command is Linux, so I'm using `git bash` in my project directory and execute this command.

The result is solved, and I can access the image.

Comment: But this work only once, We have to call this everytime when we upload new image